# Can a Shared Preference be applied to custom ListView?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have a shared preference in my `Custom list view`. I am using it to keep numbers on the button but I have a condition where the row disappears when the button becomes 0 but when I scroll down it returns to its old form and becomes visible to it's user again. Is it possible to apply the same logic for view in `SharedPreference` like to keep last situation?

My code is the following:

```
import static android.view.View.INVISIBLE;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public  MyAdapter adapter;

    Context context;

    public  ListView list;

    public int t[];

    public SharedPreferences prefs;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

    int [] btnNums={100,150,94,72,206,489,1481,731,131,91,145,137,662,770,196,351,258,131,180,1281};

    int[] images = {R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2, R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.a4, R.drawable.a5, R.drawable.a6, R.drawable.a7, R.drawable.a8, R.drawable.a9,
            R.drawable.a10, R.drawable.a11, R.drawable.a12, R.drawable.a13, R.drawable.a14, R.drawable.a15, R.drawable.a16, R.drawable.a17, R.drawable.a18, R.drawable.a19, R.drawable.a20, R.drawable.a21};
    String[] exp;
    String[] mean;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edit= this.getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_APPEND).edit();
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_APPEND);

        Resources  res=getResources();
        exp= res.getStringArray(R.array.names);
        mean=res.getStringArray(R.array.anlam);
        list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


//
//        edit.putInt("Count", btnNums.length);
//        int count = 0;
//        for (int i: btnNums){
//            edit.putInt("IntValue_" + count++, i);
//        }
//        edit.commit();
//

        int[] ret;


        int count1 = prefs.getInt("Count", 0);
        ret = new int[count1];
        for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++){
            ret[i] =prefs.getInt("IntValue_"+ i, i);

        }

        t=ret;

        if(t!=null)
        {
            adapter=new MyAdapter(this,exp,images,mean,t);
        }else
        {
            adapter=new MyAdapter(this,exp,images,mean,btnNums);
        }

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        context=getApplicationContext();
    }
}

class  MyAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    int [] images;
    String [] titleArray;
    String [] descriptionArray;
    int [] btnNums;
    MainActivity ma;

    public MyAdapter(MainActivity m, String[] titles, int imgs[], String[] descp, int[] btnNum ){
        super(m, R.layout.single_row, R.id.textView,titles);
        this.images=imgs;
        this.titleArray=titles;
        this.descriptionArray=descp;
        btnNums=btnNum;
        this.ma=m;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) ma.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);

        final TextView myTitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        myTitle.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        final TextView descp=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final Button button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.angry_btn);
        final Vibrator a = (Vibrator) ma.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        if(ma.t!=null)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<21;i++){
                button.setText("" + ma.t[position]);
                imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
                myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
                descp.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
            }
        }else
        {
            for(int i=0; i<21;i++){
                button.setText("" + btnNums[position]);
                imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
                myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
                descp.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
            }
        }


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                btnNums[position]--;

                storeIntArray(btnNums);

                a.vibrate(30);
                if (btnNums[position] == 0) {
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    button.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                    row.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

                }

                int temp[]=getFromPrefs();
                ma.t=temp;

                for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
                    button.setText("" + temp[position]);
                    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
                    myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
                    descp.setText(descriptionArray[position]);

                }
            }
        });

        return row;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    public  void storeIntArray(int[] array){

        ma.edit.putInt("Count", array.length);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i: array){
            ma.edit.putInt("IntValue_" + count++, i);
        }
        ma.edit.commit();
    }

    public int[] getFromPrefs(){

        int[] ret;


        int count = ma.prefs.getInt("Count", 0);
        ret = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            ret[i] =ma.prefs.getInt("IntValue_"+ i, i);
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please format your code, so its more readable.

Question: Can a `Shared Preference` be applied to custom `ListView`?

Answer: Yes it possible to use/access shared preferences in a `Listview`.

Upon reading your code, I believe the problem lies in your implementation of `Listview and its adapter`. The reason why it gets back to original state when scrolled down. Please note, that `GetView` is always called when scrolling. 
You can refer to this topic: [ListView & ViewHolder Pattern](https://www.ricston.com/blog/optimising-listview-viewholder-pattern/).